# How to get the repackaged asm code in spring framework?

Tags: spring

I know Spring(3.2) has repackaged the asm code as org.springframework.asm.*; but I can not get the corresponding asm code from spring framework's source code (https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/tree/v3.2.3.RELEASE). This is very inconvient when I browse Spring's source code.

So can anyone know how to get the repackaged asm code in spring framework ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have to go to the ASM project for the source now, since they don't include it in Spring anymore.  Here's the link to browse the 4.0 version (what they are apparently using in Spring) on the web:

http://websvn.ow2.org/listing.php?repname=asm&path=%2Ftags%2FASM_1_4%2Fasm%2F

Here's the project site if you want more info:

http://asm.ow2.org/

Here's the downloads link if you want to download the source:

http://forge.ow2.org/project/showfiles.php?group_id=23